# Offline Map in android

Tags: android, dictionary

i want to develop an application with the use of offline map,But i have no any idea for doing the same, can anybody explain me how to integrate offline map in android?

Comment: An offline map of what? A neighborhood? A city? A state? A country? The entire world? You have to think about memory limits here. You couldn't possibly fit a map of the entire world on an Android device.

Comment: offline map for perticular state

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at [osmdroid](http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/) It can use [OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org/) data which you are allowed to cache.  You can also set it up with a pre packaged set of tiles for a totaly offline solution.

Answer (score 1):

This involves a lot of LOT OF work to accomplish and to support my saying you can see that there are only 2 (in my knowledge) maps providers, Google and MS.
But yes, some one needs to do this, why not you.
So for this you require hell lot of data, implement the vector rendering of the map tiles including their zooming scrolling etc etc.
The biggest hurdle of it is to get the geo location data, I mean atleast I dont know the source to get it, as I dont think Google is gonna provide any API to get the geo location data that it uses.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your app will be monetizable (at a given growth stage) you could go for a commercial licence:

1. OSM based (I guess your cheapest version): skobbler/Telenav  - full offline maps (download on request or prebundle): http://developer.skobbler.com/features
2. Microsoft/Nokia - full offline maps (maybe the most reliable maps): [http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Category:HERE_Maps](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Category%3aHERE_Maps)
3. TomTom - http://developer.tomtom.com/products/Android_SDK