# How can i use open street map in offline mode

Tags: openstreetmap

I was be able to display a *Map* but uses internet so it required the `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` permission.

I don't want to use this. I want to make a project that works offline. I want to display a map which is stored in one of the folders in my project and display it programmatically.

It should be offline, and should be able to zoom in/out.

Please share your thoughts in this.

Thank you!

Comment: A rather similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23541828/app-openstreetmap-for-android-ios

Comment: Or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9264791/offline-map-in-android?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Please see [Offline OpenStreetMap](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Offline_Openstreetmap) in the OSM wiki.

Your question lacks a lot of details. You have to decide whether you want to just display pre-rendered [tiles](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tiles) (images) or [render](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Rendering) your own ones instead. You have do decide if you need a search function by using a geocoder like [Nominatim](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim), if you need [routing](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing), if you need meta information about specific POIs (addresses, opening hours, ...) etc.